# How to Patch a BigQuery View using Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have a Cloud Function written in the Node.js v8 that uses the [@google-cloud/bigquery v1.3.0](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/1.3.x/) library.

I like it, I'm able to perform BigQuery changes such as creating a view using the very simple code below without worry about promises and it's synchronous.

```
const bigquery = new BigQuery({projectId: 'my-project'});

const options = {
    view: {
        query: 'SELECT * FROM `my-project.my-datatset.my-table`',
        useLegacySql: false
    }
};

results = await bigquery
 .dataset('my-datatset')
 .createTable('my-view', options);
```

But I've been unable to work out how this code can be modified to perform a **patch** operations.  I would expect a very similar syntax to be available but I can't find it.  E.g. none of the examples below work:

```
//bigquery.dataset(datasetId).patchTable(viewId,options);
//bigquery.dataset(datasetId).table(viewId).patch(options);
//bigquery.dataset(datasetId).tables(viewId).patch(options);
```

I'm able to do the patch operation I want using [the rest API through Googles reference documents](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/patch).  But I just can't find a code solution that's consistent with the approach above.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you have a basic misunderstanding that using the keyword `await` is "synchronous". Also, the function `.dataset` _does_ return a promise, so "without worry of promises" kind of goes out the window doesn't it? [see documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/1.3.x/Dataset#createTable)

Comment: I'm sorry if my terminology is poor/misleading.  What I want is to get the result into the result object before the next line of code is executed.  I.e. I don't want have a subsequent loop to keep checking the result object for a completed status before continuing.  That said do you know how to patch a BigQuery view using Node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is longer and asynchronous, but it seems to work.  In case anyone runs into the same problem

```
var {google} = require('googleapis');
var bigQuery = google.bigquery("v2")

google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function(err, authClient) {
    if (err) {
        //Handle error
    }

    if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
        var scopes = [
            //Either scope is sufficient according to the spec.
            //https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/patch
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'
        ];  
        authClient = authClient.createScoped(scopes);
    }

    var request = {
        projectId: 'my-project',
        datasetId:'my-datatset',
        tableId:'my-view',

        resource: {
            view: {
                query: 'SELECT * FROM `my-project.my-datatset.my-table`',
                useLegacySql: false
            }
        },
        // Auth client
        auth: authClient
    };

    tables = bigQuery.tables;
    tables.patch(request, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            //Handle error
        } else {
            //Print response
        }
    });  
});
```